# grails spring security plugin - why does AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler always remove the saved request?

Tags: grails, spring-security

In our app we need to handle an unauthenticated POST, redirect to login, then redirect to the original destination with the POST body.

By default, grails uses the AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, which always removes the saved request.  This breaks the default (working) behavior of the saved request use case.

Its parent class, SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, has a little logic to only remove the saved request based on configuration settings.

So...why does AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler always clear out the cached request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general once the redirect happens the saved request shouldn't be needed, so it's removed to reduce the size of the session. If you want I can make it configurable - create a JIRA and I'll get it in for 2.0 final.